# How to filter Experience Analytics for Sitecore goals by page

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

We are using Sitecore 9.3 and are triggering goals using the sc_trk param on clicks of links/buttons.
We would like to be able to have a Filter dropdown of Sitecore Pages within the Goals report in Experience Analytics which will allow the report to only show Goals triggered from a certain page.
E.g:

> If we have a Goal called 'Signup CTA Clicked' then we would like to
> Show a Report for all clicks on the 'Signup CTA' where the user was on
> the homepage.

We store the referring page ID and Url in the [data property](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/triggering-custom-events.html) of the Goal when we trigger it from the link/button click. So this is what we would need to match against in the report filter.

I've read over [quite](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/filter-analytics-goal-report-by-device) [a](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/filtering-xdb-reports-by-ip-address) [few](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19115/how-to-do-filtering-and-sorting-on-pages-by-url-in-experience-analytics) different posts on this and the official Sitecore documentation on adding custom [filters and segments](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-custom-report-filter-and-segment.html) and [creating custom reports](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/creating-a-custom-experience-analytics-report.html).

However none of this really fully explains how to achieve what I want. I am not sure if I need an custom segment and filter or an custom metric and if I also need to create a [custom filter component](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/extending-sitecore-experience-analytics-filters) or combination of these. Any help would be much appreciated.